Migrating MariaDB 10.4.24 from server to my local computer has different sizes and rows
So I use MariaDB as my database and I'm using HeidiSQL as my GUI. I tried to migrate the database from the server to my local computer so I can safely work my API using the database from my local computer. But there's something which makes me wonder, I export the database with drop and create option, but when I run the sql file to be imported to my local computer. In my local computer I made changes where I alter id of a table from int to varchar(12) (my senior ask me to make it into varchar), of course I also alter all other table's foreign key which pinpoint to this id. This made the database has different number of rows in some of the tables and the size is smaller. There are more rows now in my local computer but the size is smaller which to me logically the size should be bigger since it change from int to varchar.
I expect the imported database should have the same number of rows and the size should be bigger since I changed some fields from int to varchar. What am I doing wrong?

If the numbers are small, this is to be expected.  An int takes 4 bytes.  Small numbers might take less.

from int to varchar(12)?!?

varchar 12 is a bizarre thing to have as id.  normal ids are int, bigint (if you expect to get up into the billions) or uuid.  using anything else is likely a kludge to do something best done another way

"...so I can safely work my API [locally]..." -- Then make sure you have the EXACT same database structure. Don't improve it.
